# CodeIgniter correct way to set header data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm using codeigniter 4
In the docs its says to use the `setHeader` function (from within a controller)

for example:

```
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', "application/pdf");
```

in the above example I still get `'Content-Type': 'text/html'`
when I look at the response in chrome dev tools.

However, if I use the `header()` function ie:

`header("Content-Type: application/pdf");`

I get the expected result.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try $this->response->setContentType("application/pdf");
I think this is what it is changing content type in codeigniter.

Comment: it's not just content type, I'm tryping to set a bunch of headers

  $this->response->setContentType("application/pdf");
        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', "application/pdf");
        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', $fs . $fs2);
        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($fp));

Answer (score 0):

You have to chain the send method. Without send method, it is not going to change the header.

Following is a snippet as to how to use it.

```
$this->response->setContentType('application/json')->send();
```